# Wanting to keep text after certain amount of commas (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

Here is how it looks

John,Mendez,40,name1
Celine,Reo,22,name2

So what I am wanting is only the text in the name field (after third comma but) regardless of how big the values in the previous commas are. As long as it deletes the third comma and before and keeps only the text after.

Comment: Must you use notepad++ for this? Sounds like this could be easier to do with Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

`^(?:[^,]*,){3}(.*)`

Replace by: `\1`

```
^  # Begin of line
   (?: # group
      [^,]* Any non ',' character repeated 0 or more times
      ,
   ){3} # Repeat the group 3 times
   (.*) # Capture the rest of the line
```

In notepad++ we need to capture the rest of the line because if not, the regular expression could match again the same line when searching again.

**Don't** tick the 'dot matches new line' checkbox